# Pivot using multiple columns

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data set with 5 columns:

```
store_id    year    event    item    units
123         2015     sale_2   abc      2
234         2015     sale_3   def      1
345         2015     sale_2   xyz      5
```

I'm trying to rotate out the `items` by `store_id, year, and event` to get the `sum`.  For instance

```
store_id    year    event    abc     def   xyz 
123          2015    sale_2   2       0     0
234          2015    sale_3   0       1     0
345          2015    sale_2   0       0     5
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the best method.  Normally I'd use dummyVars in caret to do this but I need sums instead of flag.  I've looked at tapply but it can't handle more than 2 grouping variables.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: it looks like you meant for store 345 to be store 123 instead so that 5 + 2 = 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, store_id + year + event ~ item, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var='units')
#    store_id year  event abc def xyz
# 1:      123 2015 sale_2   2   0   0
# 2:      234 2015 sale_3   0   1   0
# 3:      345 2015 sale_2   0   0   5
```

For large datasets consider

```
# uses dcast.data.table, much faster
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dcast(df, store_id + year + event ~ item, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var='units')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
group_by(store_id, year, event, item) %>%
summarize(N = sum(units)) %>%
spread(item, N)
```

You can use dplyr to group and summarize and tidyr to spread the data into the desired item columns.